# How to edit specific html element with Javascript dom?

Tags: javascript, css

! try to edit the `span` element of specific class  with javascript dom:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0];   
let str = list.childNodes[1].textContent;
list.childNodes[1].textContent = str.substring(str.length-4, str.length);
```

I want to edit this `span` element:

```
<div class="data">
     <span>Jan. 16, 2019</span>
</div>
```

but it edits this `h1` element:

```
<div class="data">
 <h1>mma.</h1> 
 </div>
```

Can i specifi to edit only `span` of `.data` class?

Comment: Use: `document.querySelector('div.data > span')`

Comment: dooes not work :(

Comment: `var list = document.querySelector('div.data > span');   
let str = list.textContent;
list.textContent = str.substring(str.length-4, str.length);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if it's possible, give a proper identification to elements you'll handle through javascript. html elements order and class names can change with time, and with current approach you create a dependency to your javascript code that may break by you (or a teammate) in a future since at first sight you can't see at html body that bound existence between them.

proper way to identify a handled tag element would give it an id with `js--` prefix like:

```
<span id="js--dateStamp" >Jan. 16, 2019</span>
```

or data attributes:

```
<span data-js="date-stamp" >Jan. 16, 2019</span>
```

there you can access directly with:

```
const dateElm = document.querySelector('#js--date-stamp')
const dateElm = document.querySelector('[data-js=date-stamp]')
```

that way you give a clear identification that a given tag is handled by javascript by anyone and should be handled with proper care.

with either option now you can update your textContent like you want to:

```
dateElm.textContent = dateElm.textContent.substring(str.length-4, str.length)
```

fwiw, avoid declaring variables with `var` if possible. you should prefer to declare your variables nowadays with `const` or `let`.